# How to change keys of ordered dict to that of keys from other ordered dict in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have two ordered dicts `D1` and `D2`. I want to assign key names of `D2` to `D1` (overwrite existing key names of `D1`). How to do that?

Example:

```
D1 = {'first_key': 10, 'second_key': 20}
D2 = {'first_new_key': 123, 'second_new_key': 456}
```

Now I want to assign key names of `D2` to `D1` so that `D1` becomes

```
{'first_new_key': 10, 'second_new_key': 20}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just creating a new variable and then assigning over? This isn't very easy in-place, since ordered dicts maintain insertion order. But this is easy iterating over the order of insertion, and assigning `d_new[new_key] = d1[old_key]`.

Comment: I don't think you can overwrite keys, you'll need to delete the old items and add the new ones.

Comment: @Sangram if my answer helped you (or any other answer btw...), please consider accepting it. thanks :)

Comment: You can't create ordered dicts with `{}` literals, you need to use `collections.OrderedDict`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's a solution:

```
keys = D2.keys()
values = D1.values()
new_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

If your'e into 1-liners (that's why we have python, right?):

```
new_dict = dict(zip(D2.keys(), D1.values()))
```

As mentioned in the comments, the insertion order between the 2 dictionaries must match.

**EDIT**

I figured out that you want to overwrite `D1`. In that case you can simply do:

```
D1 = dict(zip(D2.keys(), D1.values()))
```

**EDIT 2**

As Barmar mentioned in another answer, in order to have ordered dictionaries, one must use [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Answer (score 2):

noamgot's answer will work if it's OK to create a new dictionary. If you need to modify the existing dictionary in place:

```
for (old_key, old_val), new_key in zip(list(D1.items()), D2.keys()):
    del D1[old_key]
    D1[new_key] = old_val
```

The `list()` wrapper are needed in Python 3 because `items()` is a generator, and you can't modify the dict being iterated over.

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/WkAin3)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is mere dictionary assignment:

```
D1 = {'first_key': 10, 'second_key': 20}
D2 = {'first_new_key': 123, 'second_new_key': 456}
D2['first_new_key'] = D1['first_key']
D2['second_new_key'] = D1['second_key']
```

However, for larger dictionaries, it may be better to use dictionary comprehension:

```
D1 = {a:D1[a.split('_')[0]+"_key"] for a, _ in D2.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'second_new_key': 20, 'first_new_key': 10}
```

Comment: I have a problem with that answer - it assumes that the keys are strings with a cretain pattern. There are more general solutions.

Comment: I guess the key OP mentioned here with `_` are just sample. It shouldn't be considered as a parameter to match keys.

Comment: You're supposed to be modifying `D1`, not `D2`, by copying the keys from `D2`.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for pointing that out. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: I also think that the keys in the question are just examples, and you can't assume that the keys in the two dicts follow a related pattern.

Comment: @Barmar Python dictionaries are not ordered.

Comment: Yeah, need to use `collections.OrderedDict`